# Animate UICollectionViewFlowLayout subclass UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes frame changes

Tags: ios, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have sub classed `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`, and in that sub class, I'm changing the `UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes` frames, so that they would appear larger or smaller - depending on their position on screen.

I'm performing the frame changes in `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect`:
And as well returning it in `layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath`:
I'm returning YES in `shouldInvalidateLayoutForBoundsChange`:

All is working well, but the cells do not animate the changes of the frame.

Am i missing Something?
Why are the changes are not being animated?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi.  Could you please include some code?  What do you mean by changing the frames so that they are larger or smaller depending upon their position?  Scroll position?  (For example, wider at the center of the screen)  I have an example where that works marvelously so I am guessing you mean something else.  Thanks!

Comment: @smallwisdom, 'changing frames' means changing the attributes of each item, so that items would appear larger at top and smaller on their way to the top (of the scrollView).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVED.

There is no "animation function", or anything similar, since changing the frames of items of a collection view inside your own custom (flow) lay out just can't be animated.

The solution to the problem is writing an algorithm that calculates all the relevant frames that the method layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: provides, so that setting the frame of an item will respectfully set another item's frame an will compensate for the added size, or reduced size.

Comment: Absolutely, if you want an animated change in the frame or any other attribute, you have to recreate the formula of changing that attribute over time, the same as apple does internally. Then in this formula you have to apply this delta value AND call invalidateLayout(), so that it gets drawn immediately. Now, I'm not sure that that's really the way to go, but honestly I haven't found any better way for a **really** custom behavior of custom UICollectionLayout element.